# Despite conventional wisdom, using + instead of | to combine bytes into an int always works?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Conventional wisdom has it that when you are ORing `bytes` together to make an `int`, you should use the `|` operator rather than the `+` operator, otherwise you could have problems with the sign bit.

But this doesn't appear to be the case in C#. It looks like you can happily use the `+` operator, and it still works even for negative results.

My questions:

- Is this really true?
- If so, why does it work? (And why do a lot of people think it shouldn't - including me! ;)

Here's a test program which I believe tests every possible combination of four bytes using the `+` operator and the `|` operator, and verifies that both approaches yield the same results.

Here's the test code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        int Convert1(byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4)
        {
            return b1 + (b2 << 8) + (b3 << 16) + (b4 << 24);
        }

        int Convert2(byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4)
        {
            return b1 | (b2 << 8) | (b3 << 16) | (b4 << 24);
        }

        void Run()
        {
            byte b = 0xff;

            Trace.Assert(Convert1(b, b, b, b) == -1); // Sanity check.
            Trace.Assert(Convert2(b, b, b, b) == -1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                byte b1 = (byte) i;

                for (int j = 0; j < 256; ++j)
                {
                    byte b2 = (byte) j;

                    for (int k = 0; k < 256; ++k)
                    {
                        byte b3 = (byte) k;

                        for (int l = 0; l < 256; ++l)
                        {
                            byte b4 = (byte) l;
                            Trace.Assert(Convert1(b1, b2, b3, b4) == Convert2(b1, b2, b3, b4));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }
    }
}
```

---

[EDIT]

To see how this works, consider this:

```
byte b = 0xff;

int i1 = b;
int i2 = (b << 8);
int i3 = (b << 16);
int i4 = (b << 24);

Console.WriteLine(i1);
Console.WriteLine(i2);
Console.WriteLine(i3);
Console.WriteLine(i4);

int total = i1 + i2 + i3 + i4;

Console.WriteLine(total);
```

This prints:

```
255
65280
16711680
-16777216
-1
```

Aha!

Comment: It works because no bits ever overlap, so there's never a carry. I've never heard of this not working though, isn't that a holdover from C where nothing is ever defined?

Comment: Well, I asked this question because an answer I made to another question it was edited to use `|` instead of `+` in case of sign bit problems.

Comment: @dlev if the bytes were signed, ORing them wouldn't work either. The upper bits would just be 1 (if any of the bytes were negative). You'd have to AND with 255 after upcasting to int.

Comment: It's bad style and causes eye cancer for experienced programmers, so don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differences:

1. When bits overlap, `|` and `+` will produce different results:

   ```
   2 | 3 = 3
   2 + 3 = 5
   ```
2. When actually using signed bytes, the result will be different:

   ```
   -2 | -3   = -1
   -2 + (-3) = -5
   ```

Comment: OK, of course that makes sense. I was somewhat put off by people "correcting" an answer I made to a question earlier. Seems like the correction was not necessary (but it's a good idea to always use `|` in any case, because it will always work even if the bits overlap).

Comment: @MatthewWatson: IMO the change to your answer was unnecessary, especially in the given context.